# PHP - Error while overwriting a file

Tags: php, file, overwrite

I have a PHP file that counts a value that increases very often:

```
<?$totI=515905;?>
```

Sometimes another file resets the $totI variable (maybe because it loads and writes it two times together).

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can do file locking with `flock()` to make sure only one process is accessing the file at once.

Comment: resets to what? a lower value? back to zero?  parallel writes would "lose" a count or two, but wouldn't reset back to zero

Comment: I include the file, then I write it with the $totI variable increased by one... but sometimes the result is <?$totI=1;?> instead of <?$totI=515906;?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by using `fopen($file,"a")` instead of `fopen($file,"w")` and by adding `ftruncate` after the `flock` function